# How to make a WinForms tri-state checkbox state display check/X/empty?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing an app to replace some paper-based testing forms.  These forms have checkboxes that the tester marks with either a check or an X depending on the test result.  How would I go about getting this visual feel from a winforms checkbox?

Comment: The CheckBox control doesn't support customizing its appearance.  Make your own by deriving a class from Control.  Override the OnPaint and OnMouseUp methods to make it look and behave like a check box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enable the `ThreeState` property.

If for the "Indeterminate" state, you would rather have an "X", you can paint this yourself (using the control's paint event). One example:

```
private void checkBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox s = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (s.CheckState == CheckState.Indeterminate)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("X", s.Font, Brushes.Black, new Point(1, 1));
}
```

You can of course draw some lines or something more graphical. Cheers!

Comment: This isn't the entire answer though. The visuals need changing too.

Comment: True, if the OP desires an "X" instead of a square.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm already aware of the ThreeState option and have that enabled.  Just looking for how to change the visual.

Comment: Using `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White,new Rectangle(new Point(4,4),New Size(6,8)))` you can clear out the `CheckState.Indeterminate` square that gets painted and then draw your custom character "X" or whatever.